# Log-based user defined metrics seem to change one another in Stackdriver

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring

I have a number of user-defined metrics in Google Stackdriver. Then I edit one of them using "Edit metric", edit the filter, and click Save.

When I look at a different user-defined metric via "Edit metric", my previous change seems to show up here too. Wtf?!?

Does anyone else have this problem? Am I doing something obviously wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's us, not you—this is a known issue with that piece of UI at the moment. We're working on getting it fixed and it should be addressed soon. Direct API access is unaffected and is a workaround for the immediate future.

By the way, if you use the feedback widget in the speech balloon in the top toolbar when you see issues like this, it captures a detailed report including things like browser version/platform/etc. that can help us track issues down. We don't need it in this case (this one is well in hand), but that may be a good course of action for the future.

Thanks for trying out Stackdriver, and for your patience with beta issues. =)